# To generate a random, single-use URL

Tags: vb.net, url-routing, security

I've published a different take on a log in system on CodeProject ( http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/mlogin.aspx ) and I've got some free time, so I thought I'd have a look at password recovery/reset.

It was suggested on the article that I look into sending the account owner a single use, random url where they can reset their password if the account gets locked because of too many invalid login attempts/forgotten password.

Can anyone provide some guidance to help me to do this?

So far, I'm thinking I just have to generate a random string in a "recovery" field in the database table for the user's row and then check if the requested URL on the site is the same as the value for that field, then dynamically draw the page server-side.

Am I thinking on the right track here, or way off the mark?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It might be a good idea to first to fix the problem inherent in the following sentence from the article: "Upon registration, a new user will be sent an email which will contain details about his/her account. These details include their user id, username, **and password."**

Comment: That will be dealt with when I start work which won't happen until I have a solid idea of how to generate a page at the random URL. Making it single use would simply be a case of generating a fresh one whenever it gets a hit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track. Rather than a random string, a GUID is sufficient (uniqueidentifier field in SQL). Use the "d" format so the URL doesn't have curly braces:

```
MyUser.RecoveryKey = Guid.NewGuid()
Dim EmailBody As String = "http://blah/recoverpass.aspx?key=" & _
   MyUser.RecoveryKey.ToString("D");
```

Comment: Building that column into the database, I'm assuming I'd use a varchar column with a default of 'new guid()' (or similar). Any recommendation about how long to make the column?